# Matching 0-9, a-z, and 1 special character in JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I currently have regexp: `\w+`. I know this means to match the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore, but I also want to match the special character *.

`AT_17*abe` would be valid `AT17%abe` would not be valid

Comment: `\w` → `[\w*]`.

Comment: It's rather direct - `/[a-z0-9*]+/` (`\w` matches underscore as well, may or may not be what you need). Spend some time on investigating the regexp syntax.

Comment: means you want to match `*` or there is any specified list of special character that you want to match?

Comment: I want to match a-z,A-Z,0-9, an underscore and an *

Comment: AT_17*abe would be valid   AT17%abe would not be valid

Answer (score 2):

```js
const re = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z0-9*]/g);
console.log("*".match(re)); // match
console.log("123".match(re)); // match
console.log("abc".match(re)); // match
console.log("!@#$%^&".match(re)); // null
console.log("123!".match(re));  // Will match 1, 2, and 3 but not !
```

`/[a-zA-Z0-9\*]/g` means "match any value of lowercase a-z, uppercase A-Z, all digits and *.

Edit: No need to escape * as pointed out in comments.

Comment: Why do you escape `*` inside character class? Also, do not use `match` to do `test` job.

Comment: You are right. No need to escape. I'll edit. Match is just there for example purposes.

Comment: I've added an example that shows a partial match.  It is unclear if OP wants the entire string to match, or just some characters in that string (this answer shows the latter).

Comment: You don't need to wrap a Regex literal in the Regex constructor, doing so just adds unneeded bytes and processing time. Instead just use `/[a-zA-Z0-9*]/g`, or better yet, use the `i` flag and simplify it to `/[a-z0-9*]/gi`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Denniss answer using test instead of match,

```js
const regEx = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9_*]*$");
console.log(regEx.test("6789")); // true
console.log(regEx.test("xyz")); // true
console.log(regEx.test("abc123")); // true
console.log(regEx.test("abc123*")); // true
console.log(regEx.test("123@#")); // false
console.log(regEx.test("AT_17*")); // true
console.log(regEx.test("AT17@abe")); // false
```

`*` means "any number of this".

`^` indicates the beginning of the string.

`$` indicates the end of the string.

Comment: how do I incorporate an underscore as a valid character

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

a-zA-Z0-9_

I needed an underscore in mine.

```
var folder = 'fsvdsv_$ve';

if (folder.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$")) {

    console.log('yes');

} else {

    console.log('no');

}
```